# autocad Install Error (Failed to install)

Tags: autocad, autolisp

I Tried to reinstall AutoCAD 2014 in my computer, but It doesn't work. It produces a log file like followings.

> 2018/4/15:00:05:57 Thaw Mobile DESKTOP-16NE0KO === Setup started on
>   DESKTOP-16NE0KO by Thaw Mobile === 2018/4/15:00:05:57 Thaw
>   Mobile    DESKTOP-16NE0KO Path_Length: 155 2018/4/15:00:05:57 Thaw
>   Mobile    DESKTOP-16NE0KO Current Directory F:\Autocad
>   2014(64bits)16.2.14 2018/4/15:00:05:57    Thaw
>   Mobile    DESKTOP-16NE0KO Launch  2018/4/15:00:05:57  Thaw
>   Mobile    DESKTOP-16NE0KO CommandLine          2018/4/15:00:05:57 Thaw
>   Mobile    DESKTOP-16NE0KO Path_Length: 155 2018/4/15:00:05:57 Thaw
>   Mobile    DESKTOP-16NE0KO Current Directory
>   C:\Users\THAWMO~1\AppData\Local\Temp_AIE8B1.tmp
>   2018/4/15:00:05:59    Thaw Mobile DESKTOP-16NE0KO === Setup ended ===
>
> 2018/4/15:00:05:57    Thaw Mobile DESKTOP-16NE0KO === Setup started on
>   DESKTOP-16NE0KO by Thaw Mobile === 2018/4/15:00:05:57 Thaw
>   Mobile    DESKTOP-16NE0KO Path_Length: 155 2018/4/15:00:05:57 Thaw
>   Mobile    DESKTOP-16NE0KO Current Directory
>   C:\Users\THAWMO~1\AppData\Local\Temp_AIE8B1.tmp
>   2018/4/15:00:05:57    Thaw Mobile DESKTOP-16NE0KO Launch 
>   2018/4/15:00:05:57    Thaw
>   Mobile    DESKTOP-16NE0KO Install CustomCallback  Info    Invoking custom
>   callback for details: [SETUP] CB_FUNC=CustomPlatformCheck
>   CB_SOURCE=C:\Users\THAWMO~1\AppData\Local\Temp_AIE8B1.tmp\Setup\AcSetup.dll
>   2018/4/15:00:05:57    Thaw
>   Mobile    DESKTOP-16NE0KO Install CustomCallback  Info    Custom callback
>   response: Status=0 SUCCECSS Title= Message= URLTitle= URLLink=
>   2018/4/15:00:05:59    Thaw Mobile DESKTOP-16NE0KO PageOpen    LaunchDialog
>   2018/4/15:00:06:01    Thaw
>   Mobile    DESKTOP-16NE0KO PageOpen    LicenseDialog
>   2018/4/15:00:06:03    Thaw
>   Mobile    DESKTOP-16NE0KO PageOpen    ProductInfoDialog
>   2018/4/15:00:06:21    Thaw
>   Mobile    DESKTOP-16NE0KO PageOpen    ProductSelectionDialog2
>   2018/4/15:00:06:26    Thaw
>   Mobile    DESKTOP-16NE0KO PageOpen    FullProgressDialog
>   2018/4/15:00:06:27    Thaw Mobile DESKTOP-16NE0KO Installing DirectX
>   Runtime: "F:\Autocad 2014(64bits)16.2.14\3rdParty\DirectX\DXSETUP.exe"
>   /silent 2018/4/15:00:07:03    Thaw Mobile DESKTOP-16NE0KO Install DirectX
>   Runtime   Succeeded    2018/4/15:00:07:03 Thaw
>   Mobile    DESKTOP-16NE0KO Installing Autodesk Material Library 2014:
>   ADSK_EULA_STATUS=#1 MUILANG=en-us SETUP_PACKAGENAME="Autodesk®
>   AutoCAD® 2014"
>   SETUP_PACKAGECODE={D54FD115-F651-4237-B57C-E4230340EAB6}
>   SETUP_UNINSTALLKEYS=1 SETUP_ISLANGUAGEPACK=0
>   SETUP_PRODUCTDEPENDENCIES=";;;" ADSK_SOURCE_ROOT="F:\Autocad
>   2014(64bits)16.2.14\" FILESINUSETEXT="" REBOOT=ReallySuppress
>   ADSK_SETUP_EXE=1
>
> 2018/4/15:00:07:26   Thaw Mobile DESKTOP-16NE0KO Install Autodesk
>   Material Library 2014 Succeeded    2018/4/15:00:07:26 Thaw
>   Mobile    DESKTOP-16NE0KO Installing Autodesk Material Library 2014 -
>   Base Image Library:   ADSK_EULA_STATUS=#1 MUILANG=en-us
>   SETUP_PACKAGENAME="Autodesk® AutoCAD® 2014"
>   SETUP_PACKAGECODE={D54FD115-F651-4237-B57C-E4230340EAB6}
>   SETUP_UNINSTALLKEYS=1 SETUP_ISLANGUAGEPACK=0
>   SETUP_PRODUCTDEPENDENCIES=";;;" ADSK_SOURCE_ROOT="F:\Autocad
>   2014(64bits)16.2.14\" FILESINUSETEXT="" REBOOT=ReallySuppress
>   ADSK_SETUP_EXE=1
>
> 2018/4/15:00:07:42   Thaw Mobile DESKTOP-16NE0KO Install Autodesk
>   Material Library 2014 - Base Image Library    Succeeded
>   2018/4/15:00:07:43    Thaw Mobile DESKTOP-16NE0KO Installing Autodesk
>   Content Service:  INSTALLMODE=PRIVATE AUTOSTART=0
>   TRANSFORMS="F:\Autocad
>   2014(64bits)16.2.14\x64\en-us\Tools\snap\ContentService.mst"
>   ADSK_EULA_STATUS=#1 MUILANG=en-us SETUP_PACKAGENAME="Autodesk®
>   AutoCAD® 2014"
>   SETUP_PACKAGECODE={D54FD115-F651-4237-B57C-E4230340EAB6}
>   SETUP_UNINSTALLKEYS=1 SETUP_ISLANGUAGEPACK=0
>   SETUP_PRODUCTDEPENDENCIES="Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 SP1
>   Redistributable (x86),Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 SP1 Redistributable
>   (x86),.NET Framework Runtime 4.0,;;;" ADSK_SOURCE_ROOT="F:\Autocad
>   2014(64bits)16.2.14\" FILESINUSETEXT="" REBOOT=ReallySuppress
>   ADSK_SETUP_EXE=1
>
> 2018/4/15:00:07:53   Thaw Mobile DESKTOP-16NE0KO Install Autodesk
>   Content Service   Succeeded    2018/4/15:00:07:53 Thaw
>   Mobile    DESKTOP-16NE0KO Installing Autodesk Content Service Language
>   Pack:  ADSK_EULA_STATUS=#1 MUILANG=en-us SETUP_PACKAGENAME="Autodesk®
>   AutoCAD® 2014"
>   SETUP_PACKAGECODE={D54FD115-F651-4237-B57C-E4230340EAB6}
>   SETUP_UNINSTALLKEYS=0 SETUP_ISLANGUAGEPACK=1
>   SETUP_PRODUCTDEPENDENCIES=";;;" ADSK_SOURCE_ROOT="F:\Autocad
>   2014(64bits)16.2.14\" FILESINUSETEXT="" REBOOT=ReallySuppress
>   ADSK_SETUP_EXE=1
>
> 2018/4/15:00:07:57   Thaw Mobile DESKTOP-16NE0KO Install Autodesk
>   Content Service Language Pack Succeeded    2018/4/15:00:07:57 Thaw
>   Mobile    DESKTOP-16NE0KO Installing Autodesk® AutoCAD® 2014: 
>   TRANSFORMS="F:\Autocad
>   2014(64bits)16.2.14\x64\en-us\acad\acad.mst;C:\Users\THAWMO~1\AppData\Local\Temp_AIE8B1.tmp\x64\acad\acad-standalone.mst"
>   ADSK_EULA_STATUS=#1 ADSK_SOURCE_ROOT="F:\Autocad 2014(64bits)16.2.14\"
>   INSTALLDIR="C:\Program Files\Autodesk\AutoCAD 2014\" FILESINUSETEXT=""
>   REBOOT=ReallySuppress ADSK_SETUP_EXE=1
>
> 2018/4/15:00:09:12   Thaw Mobile DESKTOP-16NE0KO Install Autodesk®
>   AutoCAD® 2014 Failed  Installation aborted, Result=1603
>   2018/4/15:00:09:16    Thaw Mobile DESKTOP-16NE0KO Rollback    Autodesk
>   Content Service Language Pack Succeeded    2018/4/15:00:09:27 Thaw
>   Mobile    DESKTOP-16NE0KO Rollback    Autodesk Content Service    Succeeded
>   2018/4/15:00:09:39    Thaw Mobile DESKTOP-16NE0KO Rollback    Autodesk
>   Material Library 2014 - Base Image Library    Succeeded
>   2018/4/15:00:09:59    Thaw Mobile DESKTOP-16NE0KO Rollback    Autodesk
>   Material Library 2014 Succeeded    2018/4/15:00:09:59 Thaw
>   Mobile    DESKTOP-16NE0KO Rollback    DirectX Runtime Failed  Failure is
>   ignored, Result=1619 2018/4/15:00:10:00   Thaw
>   Mobile    DESKTOP-16NE0KO PageOpen    InstallCompleteDialog
>   2018/4/15:00:13:16    Thaw Mobile DESKTOP-16NE0KO === Setup ended ===

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

kThe interesting part is near the bottom:

> 2018/4/15:00:09:12 Thaw Mobile DESKTOP-16NE0KO Install Autodesk® AutoCAD® 2014 Failed Installation aborted, **Result=1603**

Error 1603 can mean a few things, typically, you don't have enough hard drive space or are lacking administrative rights to install at the location it's trying.

[Check here for more info](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/inventor-products/troubleshooting/caas/sfdcarticles/sfdcarticles/Error-1603-during-installation-of-Autodesk-software.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping, It is **Visual C++ RunTime Library** and **Microsoft .Net** Error that You Linked above. I uninstalled and reinstalled them again. Now, the product have been installed with ease.